# Getting correct socketPath for TypeORM config

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, google-cloud-sql, typeorm, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to connect a Cloud Run service to Cloud SQL postgres instance. I believe I'm nearly there, but am having some trouble getting the deployed instance to connect properly. My local environment can connect (via SSL) to the database intended for production, but the deployed version can't...

I'm using TypeORM, and have everything setup properly in the configuration...

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
                const socketPath = configService.get('DB_SOCKET_PATH');
                const extra = socketPath ? {
                    socketPath: socketPath,
                    ssl: {
                        rejectUnauthorized: false,
                        ca: Buffer.from(process.env.DB_SSL_CA, 'base64').toString('ascii'),
                        cert: Buffer.from(process.env.DB_SSL_CERT, 'base64').toString('ascii'),
                        key: Buffer.from(process.env.DB_SSL_KEY, 'base64').toString('ascii'),
                    }
                } : { };

                return ({
                    type: 'postgres',
                    host: socketPath || configService.get('DB_HOST'),
                    port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
                    username: configService.get('DB_USER'),
                    password: configService.get('DB_PASS'),
                    database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
                    extra: extra,
                    entities: [__dirname + '/../../modules/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
                    namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
                    synchronize: true,
                });
            }
        })
    ]
})
export class DatabaseModule { }
```

Despite that I'm getting an error when I try to use the socketPath as the host rather than the actual host variable (necessary for GCP). It seems that TypeORM is adding extra characters, `/.s.PGSQL.5432`, at the end of my connection string that I don't want. And just to clarify, the socket path is in the form of `/cloudsql/<PROJECT_ID>:<REGION>:<INSTANCE>`.

```sh
[Nest] 28532   - 02/15/2021, 2:25:07 PM   [ExceptionHandler] connect ENOENT <DB_SOCKET_PATH>/.s.PGSQL.5432 +3ms
Error: connect ENOENT <DB_SOCKET_PATH>/.s.PGSQL.5432
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
```

At an older point in time, this used to work for me but I guess something changed in the TypeORM library. Does anybody have any ideas on this? Thanks!

EDIT: As of now I've gotten it to connect to the server correctly, but it's now giving me an error that says the server doesn't support SSL connections, which makes no sense given that I can connect via SSL fine on my local machine...?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: The issue does not seem to any code's fault, but rather some networking stuff on the GCP side. I configured the service and database to run through a VPC then just used a private IP address for the host.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that TypeORM is adding extra characters, `/.s.PGSQL.5432`

This is actually intended - the Postgres spec requires that the unix sockets end with this suffix.

> [Nest] 28532   - 02/15/2021, 2:25:07 PM   [ExceptionHandler] connect ENOENT <DB_SOCKET_PATH>/.s.PGSQL.5432 +3ms

The error means that the socket wasn't found - usually because there was a misconfiguration and the Cloud SQL proxy couldn't start. You can check your logs at the instance start up to see if the proxy left any errors, but generally it'll come down to the following:

1. The Cloud SQL Admin API needs to be enabled
2. Your service account needs to have `Cloud SQL Connect` IAM role (or equivalent)
3. The service needs to be configured for Cloud SQL.

For a full list of instructions, see the [Connecting from Cloud Run to Cloud SQL page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run).